# Loop code keeps copying from the same excel spreadsheet in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

So I was trying to create a list of excel files in a folder (file name and path) and then use a For loop to copy and paste a specified worksheet for all of the files listed into a specified worksheet in the excel workbook that contains the macro. So far everything works except for the fact that the same file keeps getting copied and pasted over instead of all the files. The macro loops for the correct number of times, but it's not using all the excel files.

**Here's the code:**

First part for listing the files in the folder

```
Private Sub btn_LeaveReport()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Administration\Time Sheets")
i = 2
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Name
    'print file path
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

and this is the part for the loop

```
Private Sub btn_PullData()
'Declared Variables
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim StartAt As Integer
Dim EndAt As Integer
Dim CopyPath As String
Dim CopyPathRow As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer

'Ranges
StartAt = 1
EndAt = Val(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LeaveReport").Range("A1"))
CopyPathRow = 3
CopyPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LeaveReport").Range("C" & CopyPathRow)
iRow = 3

'Loop de loop
For i = StartAt To EndAt
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(CopyPath)
    Sheets("TIMESHEET").Select
    Range("C12:S34").Select
    Selection.Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("Pastebin").Select
    Range("a" & iRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    iRow = iRow + 39
    CopyPathRow = CopyPathRow + 1
    wbk.Close True
Next i

Sheets("Pastebin").Select
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Timesheet Data Imported"
End Sub
```

**Based on the source of the error, i.e. same file being used, I'm guessing the issue lies with the part that has this:**

CopyPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LeaveReport").Range("C" & CopyPathRow)

**and is "supposed" to update in the For loop via this:**

CopyPathRow = CopyPathRow + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line

`CopyPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LeaveReport").Range("C" & CopyPathRow)`

Inside the loop, that value of `CopyPath` is never being changed, but the value of `CopyPathRow` is.

*Edit: I wouldn't call this recursion either.*

Comment: ah okay, I was wondering if it was something like that. By the way, just to clear up my confusion what is the difference between a recursion and just like a loop formula? I looked at some definition and it sounded similar

Comment: At a very high level they _can_ provide the same functionality. I think recursion is much more complex and a bit more demanding on the mental horsepower, but there are (like all programming concepts) reasons for using it and not using it. I'll defer to to a good [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/182334/132781) from Programmers.